# How do I get ngrams array string and estfrequency as seperate elements in a hive table using HiveQL?

Tags: json, hadoop, twitter, hive, hiveql

I am analyzing my own tweets and I have inserted the data into the Hive table using [Hive JSON SerDE](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) . I want to find out the frequency of all two word phrases in my tweets as a table. The output should look something like:

```
phrase             frequency
["the","room"]      1248.0
["a","boy"]        1039.0
["rt","to"]        1032.0
["to","ct"]         986.0
```

Right now, I am able to do it for all single word phrases and I am getting the output as:

```
phrase     frequency
["the"]     1248.0
["a"]       1039.0
["rt"]      1032.0
["to"]      986.0
["you"]     828.0
```

For the one word phrase output, my code is:

```
create table ng(new_ar array<struct<ngram:array<string>,estfrequency:double>>);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ng 
SELECT context_ngrams(sentences(lower(text)),array(null),100) as word 
FROM tweets;

create table wordFreq (ngram array<string>,  estfrequency double);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE wordFreq 
SELECT X.ngram, X.estfrequency 
FROM ng LATERAL VIEW explode(new_ar) Z as X;    

select * from wordFreq;
```

How do I modify the above code for my desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change your code from 1-grams, to 2-grams, change `array(null)` to `array(null,null)`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: That is the answer to the question!

Comment: I've made my answer a little longer.

Answer (score 0):

The below modification will give the two words in separate column. 
You could concatenate them

```
create table wordFreq (word1 string, word2 string,  estfrequency double);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE wordFreq 
SELECT X.ngram[0],X.ngram[1], X.estfrequency 
FROM ng LATERAL VIEW explode(new_ar) Z as X;
```